# how to delete a text node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

please help remove the text node "Бесплатно!".

here's my attempt on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/njrx95td/2/). the problem is that I only delete the first node, but others remain

Here is the simplified code:

```
<ul class="product_list_widget">
    <li>
        <a href="http://qqq.ru/shop/granit/104/" title="qqq">
            <img width="90" height="90" src="http://qqq.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/104-90x90.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="104">
            qqq                 
        </a> 

        <div class="star-rating" title="Рейтинг 3.50 из 5">
            <span style="width:70%">
                <strong class="rating">3.50</strong> из 5</span>
                <b class="rate_content">Рейтинг 3.50 из 5</b>
        </div>deleteNode
    </li>

    ......
    ......
    ......
    ......
</ul>


<script>
// priceless hide
document.querySelector('.star-rating').parentNode.removeChild( document.querySelector('.star-rating').nextSibling );
</script>
```

Comment: Well, `querySelector` *does* select only a single element. If you want to remove multiple nodes, you'll need to use `querySelectorAll` and then loop over them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('.star-rating')
```

will give you only **first matching node**.

You should use document.querySelectorAll which will return a **node list**

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('.star-rating');
for(var i in x){
    x[i].parentNode.removeChild( x[i].nextSibling );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to delete every element containing "Бесплатно!" using jQuery (is this what you mean by text node?) then you can use the jQuery `:contains` selector to find these elements, and remove them:

```
$("li:contains('Бесплатно!')").remove();
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1zmwfwtu/1/) demonstrating this.

If you're not looking to delete the entire node (it's not so clear from your question), then `$("li:contains('Бесплатно!')")` is a jQuery object containing all of the elements whose children you're looking to delete elements from.  This would make it easier for you to find the appropriate `<li>` children and remove them from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Your "Бесплатно!" text is not in an element by itself. It is under the li element, and removing that element would not be desirable I imagine. You could manipulate its `innerHTML` to remove that text.

```js
var li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  li[i].innerHTML = li[i].innerHTML.replace("Бесплатно!", "");
}
```

```html
<ul class="product_list_widget">
  <li>
    <a href="http://plastushka.ru/shop/granit/103/" title="Мансуровский">
      <img width="90" height="90" src="http://plastushka.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/1031-90x90.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="103" />Мансуровский
    </a>
    <div class="star-rating" title="Рейтинг 5.00 из 5"><span style="width:100%"><strong class="rating">5.00</strong> из 5</span><b class="rate_content">Рейтинг 5.00 из 5</b>

    </div>Бесплатно!</li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://plastushka.ru/shop/granit/193/" title="Сахара">
      <img width="90" height="90" src="http://plastushka.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/193-90x90.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="193">Сахара</a>
    <div class="star-rating" title="Рейтинг 5.00 из 5"><span style="width:100%"><strong class="rating">5.00</strong> из 5</span><b class="rate_content">Рейтинг 5.00 из 5</b>

    </div>Бесплатно!</li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://plastushka.ru/shop/granit/215/" title="Южно-Султаевский">
      <img width="90" height="90" src="http://plastushka.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/215-90x90.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="215">Южно-Султаевский</a>
    <div class="star-rating" title="Рейтинг 4.67 из 5"><span style="width:93.4%"><strong class="rating">4.67</strong> из 5</span><b class="rate_content">Рейтинг 4.67 из 5</b>

    </div>Бесплатно!</li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://plastushka.ru/shop/granit/287/" title="Жельтау-5">
      <img width="90" height="90" src="http://plastushka.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/287-90x90.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="287">Жельтау-5</a>
    <div class="star-rating" title="Рейтинг 4.50 из 5"><span style="width:90%"><strong class="rating">4.50</strong> из 5</span><b class="rate_content">Рейтинг 4.50 из 5</b>

    </div>Бесплатно!</li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://plastushka.ru/shop/granit/104/" title="Камбулатовский">
      <img width="90" height="90" src="http://plastushka.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/104-90x90.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="104">Камбулатовский</a>
    <div class="star-rating" title="Рейтинг 3.50 из 5"><span style="width:70%"><strong class="rating">3.50</strong> из 5</span><b class="rate_content">Рейтинг 3.50 из 5</b>

    </div>Бесплатно!</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Set some id to that nod and remove it with 
$( "#that-nod-id" ).remove();